# Swift 3.0 quick help option key

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8

I'm a total beginner in Swift, so I always find the quick help in Swift 2.2, Xcode 7 very useful(You hold down option key and click on something and the Xcode would give you a pop-up window containing all sorts of information about the variable you are clicking on). However, after I updated to Swift 3.0 the pop-up window becomes blank and a message "No Quick help". I'm wondering if someone could tell me how to bring the quick help back, thank you!

Comment: Try cleaning your project

Comment: If you updated but still have errors in your code you will probably need to fix your code. If you can't fix your code, just create a new  project and it should work there.

Comment: After I restart it it somehow works again..thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

This is an Xcode question. Quick Help only works with Swift when you don't have any errors before or in the current line you want to open the Quick Help from.

I also experienced this and it seems this feature worked much better with older Xcode versions. But I guess this has to do with Swift because it is such a fast growing programming language. The integrated interpreter of Xcode isn't able to keep up with it.

To work around it, just comment out all failing lines of code and then comment in one line by one while fixing the errors. Sometimes it is helpful to also clean up the generated project files. And if this also doesn't work, just restart Xcode.
The last step is often necessary when you're in a Playground.